# Minikube | Ingress Service - Bad Request

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

I'm working on a single-node cluster which works fine with docker-compose but the reconfiguration of the same setup using Minikube Ingress Controller gives me a `Bad Request` response.

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

My Ingress looks like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: emr-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 443
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: erp-cluster-ip-service
                port:
                  number: 8069
```

How to fix this?

Comment: whats port `emr-cluster-ip-service` service is running on ?

Comment: port: 443
targetPort: 443

Answer (score 1):

You are exposing HTTPS service on HTTP ingress, which is not the right thing to do. You might want to do one of the following:

1. Configure [TLS-enabled ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls).
2. Configure [TLS passthough](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#ssl-passthrough) on ingress object.

In both cases you also need to set `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"`

Comment: alright, thanks - let me go digging and see what I can do with this